# 'IndexOutOfBoundsException: Out of bound access on segment ...' when accessing pointer read from MemorySegment

Tags: java, project-panama, java-21, java-ffm

I am attempting to test the Foreign Function and Memory features of Java 21. Here is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 1. Find foreign function on the C library path
        Linker linker = Linker.nativeLinker();
        SymbolLookup stdlib = linker.defaultLookup();
        MethodHandle radixsort = linker.downcallHandle(stdlib.find("radixsort").orElseThrow(), FunctionDescriptor.ofVoid(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_CHAR));
        // 2. Allocate on-heap memory to store four strings
        String[] javaStrings = {"mouse", "cat", "dog", "car"};

        // 3. Use try-with-resources to manage the lifetime of off-heap memory
        try (Arena offHeap = Arena.ofConfined()) {
            // 4. Allocate a region of off-heap memory to store four pointers
            MemorySegment pointers = offHeap.allocateArray(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, javaStrings.length);
            // 5. Copy the strings from on-heap to off-heap
            for (int i = 0; i < javaStrings.length; i++) {
                MemorySegment cString = offHeap.allocateUtf8String(javaStrings[i]);
                pointers.setAtIndex(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, i, cString);
                assert cString.getUtf8String(0).length() > 0;
            }
            // 6. Sort the off-heap data by calling the foreign function
            radixsort.invoke(pointers, javaStrings.length, MemorySegment.NULL, '\0');
            // 7. Copy the (reordered) strings from off-heap to on-heap
            for (int i = 0; i < javaStrings.length; i++) {
                MemorySegment cString = pointers.getAtIndex(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, i);
                javaStrings[i] = cString.getUtf8String(0);
            }
        } // 8. All off-heap memory is deallocated here
        catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        assert Arrays.equals(javaStrings, new String[]{"car", "c∞at", "dog", "mouse"});  // true
    }
```

but I am encountering this error :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Out of bound access on segment MemorySegment{ heapBase: Optional.empty address:105553153094096 limit: 0 }; new offset = 0; new length = 1`

At the line :

`javaStrings\[i\] = cString.getUtf8String(0);`
It seems that `MemorySegment cString = pointers.getAtIndex(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, i);` returns a MemorySegment with a byteSize = 0

When I use `cString.getUtf8String(0);` on the original cString, I do not encounter an error.

It seems that `pointers.setAtIndex` and `pointers.getAtIndex` do not preserve the MemorySegment byteSize. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems that pointers.setAtIndex and pointers.getAtIndex do not preserve the MemorySegment byteSize. ?

Yes, that is correct. The address is stored into off-heap memory as a plain memory address. The size is dropped. So, when reading an address back from off-heap memory, the created memory segment has size 0.

This is explained in the [javadoc of MemorySegment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/MemorySegment.html#wrapping-addresses) as well:

> When interacting with foreign functions, it is common for those
> functions to allocate a region of memory and return a pointer to that
> region. Modeling the region of memory with a memory segment is
> challenging because the Java runtime has no insight into the size of
> the region. **Only the address of the start of the region, stored in the
> pointer, is available**.
>
> ...
>
> The MemorySegment API uses zero-length memory segments to represent:
>
> - pointers returned from a foreign function;
> - pointers passed by a foreign function to an upcall stub; and
> - pointers read from a memory segment (more on that below).

Your use case is the latter of the three.

You have to use [`MemorySegment::reinterpret`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/MemorySegment.html#reinterpret(long)) to resize the segment explicitly. Since for a C string the actual size is not known (it's indicated by a null terminator), you can resize the segment to `Long.MAX_VALUE` to make it accessible:

```
// 7. Copy the (reordered) strings from off-heap to on-heap
for (int i = 0; i < javaStrings.length; i++) {
    MemorySegment cString = pointers.getAtIndex(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, i);
    cString = cString.reinterpret(Long.MAX_VALUE); // <----
    javaStrings[i] = cString.getUtf8String(0);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can create an `AddressLayout` with a [target layout](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/AddressLayout.html#withTargetLayout(java.lang.foreign.MemoryLayout)) that has the needed size, to avoid the separate call to `reinterpret`:

```
AddressLayout UNBOUNDED_POINTER = ValueLayout.ADDRESS
        .withTargetLayout(MemoryLayout.sequenceLayout(Long.MAX_VALUE, ValueLayout.JAVA_BYTE));
```

And then use that to do the dereference:

```
// 7. Copy the (reordered) strings from off-heap to on-heap
for (int i = 0; i < javaStrings.length; i++) {
    MemorySegment cString = pointers.getAtIndex(UNBOUNDED_POINTER, i);
    // no reinterpret needed
    javaStrings[i] = cString.getUtf8String(0);
}
```